# Instagram iPhone Hook Shows Other Icons on UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

My goal is to share photo to Instagram via UIDocumentInteractionController, with which only present Instagram icon exclusively.

I followed the instruction in https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

It used to work very well, the document interaction controller shows up and with only Instagram icon.

```
let writePath = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")
if !imageData.writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true) {
    Swell.error("failed save image to path.")

}
let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(writePath)

let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL!)
documentController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
```

Recently, however, other icons started to show up besides Instagram if user turns the options on in "More".

[image]

**Without restricting to Instagram exclusively, usually there are more activities when opening "More" option.**

[image]

Is there any way that I can empty all the sharing options except for Instagram?

Comment: This issue exist in iOS 8 and later versions.

Comment: @Srinivas Thanks. It's a new convention or a bug?

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same result in iOS 8.3.

This is remarkably annoying. I have filed a radar for it.